# Connecting Local Kibana to remote aws elastic search end point?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I have elastic search endpoint link I configured that in kibana.yml file by changing the elastic search url field but it is not able to establish a connection with aws end point

This is the log I am getting in kibana

log   [06:17:02.754] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] Unable to revive connection: https://search-xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:80/

Comment: Please do not forget to mark it as answer if the answer helped! Thanks!

Comment: HI @ben5556 i tried changing that it doesnt solve the problem

Comment: Ok, what do you see in logs now ? Post your kibana config

Comment: log   [10:55:04.637] [info][listening][server][http] Server running at http://localhost:5601
  log   [10:55:07.643] [error][status][plugin:elasticsearch@6.4.2] Status changed from yellow to red - Request Timeout after 3000ms

Same log was shown with the port number :80 present in url

Comment: Are you able to access Elasticsearch endpoint from your local machine ? Please post the output of `https://search-xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_cluster/health` accessing from your local machine

Comment: @ben5556 {"cluster_name":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx","status":"green","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":4,"number_of_data_nodes":4,"active_primary_shards":4,"active_shards":14,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":100.0} this is the response i got

Comment: OK please try configuring elasticsearch.url in Kibana as `https://search-xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443` if you already did not try.

Comment: Or try `http://search-xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:80` but not secure. Try the above first!

Answer (score 1):

Try kibana docker, also try 9200 for the port if 80 doesn't work

```
docker run -p 5601:5601 -d -e "XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED=false"  -e "ELASTICSEARCH_URL=YOUR_ELASTICSEARCH:9200" --add-host elasticsearch:YOUR_ELASTICSEARCH docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint url doesn't look right. Can you try `https://search-xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com` instead ? As HTTPS is port 443, appending `:80` to the url is invalid.

Also, ensure your Elasticsearch domain access policy allows connections from your network.

Comment: This doesnt  make any difference problem is same with or with out ":80" in the url